# Creating an invoice in QuickBooks via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a rails app where I have a model invoice. It interacts with quick books through api and I want to export my local invoices to quick books. I can't figure out   how to export them to quick books.

According to this link
http://ippdocs.intuit.com/0025_QuickBooksAPI/0050_Data_Services/030_Entity_Services_Reference/Invoice , "Creating an Invoice" section, I have to do this:

```
current_user.invoices do |invoice|
  data = { 
    "Line" => [
      {
        "Amount" => 100.00, 
        "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail", "SalesItemLineDetail" => {"ItemRef" => {value: 1, name: "Services"}}
      }
    ],
    "CustomerRef" => {value: 21}
  }

  consumer = create_consumer
  response = consumer.post "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/#{my_company_id}/invoice", data
  p "-------response:-------", response
end
```

But it never prints anything to console and there is no error either. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What does the `value` key refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try adding the `CustomerName`. In the version 2 API the `CustomerName` was required for invoices even though the documentation said otherwise. I am not sure if this has been corrected in the new version 3 API.

**Update and Correction**: `CustomerName` xml node does not exist on the v3 API for the `Invoice` entity.

Also, let me highly suggest the [quickbooks-ruby](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) gem. It is rapidly becoming mature, is very active with [14 contributors](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/graphs/contributors), and has rich [tutorials and screencasts](http://minimul.com).

Comment: I using exact this gem. What's CurstomerName, where can I read about it?

Comment: I guess you're the creator of this gem.

Comment: I am not the creator but I am a contributor. Oops there is no CustomerName in v3. I am going to edit the answer. From your sample code it doesn't appear that you are using the gem.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby is definitely the de-facto Ruby to QB library